# Where are the rules for drowning or suffocation?

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-2e, environmental-hazards

How does drowning/suffocation work in Chronicles of Darkness?  I don't see rules for it in the core book.

Answer (score 4):

The act of *drowning someone* is described in **Hurt Locker** on page 25. Succeed at a Hold result for a number of rounds equal to double the victim’s Stamina. Victims who need to breathe die, or are pulled away and become Beaten Down.

This doesn't quite dovetail with the Hardy merit, which adds dice to rolls to resist things that include suffocation. My guess is that it's meant to resist the Choke Hold maneuver (p.60), and can be used to roll to counter the "hold" of the ocean waves.